# How to pass cipher list to OpenSSL s_client

Tags: openssl, cipher-selection

How we can pass a cipher list to the OpenSSL `s_client` program?

We can pass single cipher by this:

```
openssl s_client -cipher 'ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA' -connect www.google.com:443
```

But how to pass a list of multiple ciphers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the documentation of OpenSSL lacks a lot, this part is actually well documented. From the [man page of s_client](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/s_client.html):

> -cipher cipherlist
>
> this allows the cipher list sent by the client to be modified. Although the server determines which cipher suite is used it should take the first supported cipher in the list sent by the client. See the ciphers command for more information.

And in the mentioned [documentation for ciphers](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-ciphers.html) you will actually find lots of details about the format of the cipher list, the cipher strings and the cipher suite names. In fact the documentation is so extensive that it is much better to read it [there](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-ciphers.html#CIPHER-LIST-FORMAT) than to include it in this answer.

Comment: Hi, I think those documentation links have changed since you linked to them. I don't see anything on your 3rd link about CIPHER LIST FORMAT. Thanks

Comment: @TrojanName: thanks, I've fixed the last two links.

Answer (score 5):

As Steffen Ullrich has [mentioned](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/93148/2630), you can pass a *list* of ciphers to the `-cipher` option of [`s_client`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/s_client.html). This is not a single item, but a specification and can also be used for the nginx [`ssl_ciphers`](http://nginx.org/r/ssl_ciphers) option, or the Apache [`SSLCipherSuite`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslciphersuite) option.

You can pass multiple ciphers using a space, comma or colon separator. Example:

```
openssl s_client -cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 \
    -connect example.com:443
```

The above list specifies two specific ciphers. A group of ciphers can also be passed. Here is an example of a cipher list specification that requires authenticated empheral ECDH key agreement (ECDH), RSA for authentication and only cipher suites that are considered of "high" encryption:

```
openssl s_client -cipher ECDH+aRSA+HIGH -connect example.com:443
```

What does this expand to? The `openssl ciphers` command can be used for this purpose:

```
$ openssl ciphers ECDH+aRSA+HIGH
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
```

or more verbosely:

```
$ openssl ciphers -v ECDH+aRSA+HIGH
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
```

For more information, read the [`ciphers` manual page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ciphers.html).

Comment: You wrote: "You can pass multiple ciphers using a space, comma or colon separator. Example:  openssl s_client -cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384  -connect example.com:443.  The above specifies just a single, specific cipher."  I'm confused, isn't that a list of two ciphers, separated by a colon in the middle, demonstrating the list syntax that you were talking about?

Comment: @Bennett You're right, there were two ciphers. The intent was to contrast specification of a fixed cipher (`ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA`) against cipher strings which match more than one cipher (`ECDH`). I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 3):

It has exactly the same syntax, as eg. `SSLCipherSuite` configuration setting in Apache, or many similar configuration switches. Example list:
`EDH+CAMELLIA:EDH+aRSA:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+SHA384:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECDH:+CAMELLIA256:+AES256:+CAMELLIA128:+AES128:!SSLv2:!SSLv3:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!DSS:!RC4:!SEED:!ECDSA:CAMELLIA256-SHA:AES256-SHA:CAMELLIA128-SHA:AES128-SHA`

Note the important characters:

```
:
+
!
```